# Weird ruby syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this code generated for scaffold:

```
assert_difference('Day.count') do
  post :create, day: @day.attributes
end
```

you see? It's not `:day => @day.attributes`, it's `day: @day.attributes`. One of my two dev environments doesn't complain, another one complains, and production doesn't complain. Am I going crazy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just new ruby 1.9 syntax.  You can track ruby syntax changes at [eigenclass.org](http://eigenclass.org) :-)

EDIT: Which seems to be malformed somehow.  Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I expect one of your environments is using Ruby 1.9.2, and one environment is on an older version of Ruby.

What you're seeing is a form of [named parameters](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Named_parameters#Ruby) (sometimes known as "keyword parameters") that provides syntactic sugar around the older hash mechanism that almost provided named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

That's the newer ruby 1.9 hash syntax.  Personally, I never made the switch.  The good old arrows are fine with me.  One of your environments apparently doesn't support it.